# CURL Operation failed

Tags: linux, curl

I want to make this upload to my server:

`curl -u ****:**** -T - sftp://*****.com:22/apps/jboss-5.1.0/server/fab_server/deploy -v -k`

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to ****.com port 22 (#0)
*   Trying ****...
* Connected to ****.com (****) port 22 (#0)
* SSH MD5 fingerprint: ****
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
* Using ssh public key file /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
* Using ssh private key file /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
* Initialized password authentication
* Authentication complete
* Upload failed: Operation failed (4/-31)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host ****.com left intact
curl: (79) Upload failed: Operation failed (4/-31)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: First thing to try is to replace the above screenshot by plain text.  It won't fix your problem, but it may improve your chances of getting an answer on [unix.se].

Comment: Alright @SatoKatsura

Comment: According to the manual, error 4 means "A feature or option that  was  needed  to  perform  the  desired request  was  not  enabled  or was explicitly disabled at build-time. To make curl able to do this, you  probably  need  another build of libcurl!".

Comment: I installed the latest version of libcurl @SatoKatsura

Comment: That still leaves "[an] option [that] ... was not enabled or was explicitly disabled at build-time". Now, to find out what option might that be, you probably need to to run `curl` with `--trace` or `--trace-ascii`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem; I had to specify the target filename.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same kind of problem by adding a "/" character in the destination's directory path, like this:

```
curl --insecure --user ****:**** -T ./sourcefile.txt sftp://DestinationIP/directory/
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It was exactly my issue. Upvoting now.